# NSSliderCell: subclass to draw custom knob

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscell, nsslider

I need to subclass NSSliderCell to customise its appearance.
I had no problem with the bar, I overrode

```
- (void)drawBarInside:(NSRect)aRect flipped:(BOOL)flipped
```

and it works as expected.

```
- (void)drawKnob:(NSRect)knobRect
```

works as well, but I want a smaller knob, and resizing the NSRect isn't an option, because I have an unwanted space either on the right or on the left (or both, if I center my custom knob).

Reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSliderCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html), I should override

```
- (void)drawKnob
```

to calculate the rect in which the knob should be drawn, then call drawKnob:
The problem is that, trying to get the cellSize to compute where I should draw the knob, I get an absurd width : 40000

How can I get the right width? NSSliderCell is a subclass of NSCell, so I can't access frame/bounds.

Comment: Try overriding `-knobThickness` as well. I can't remember if that's necessary or not.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer, then. >_>

Comment: @Wevah, setting knobThickness doesn't work, knobRect always returns same width, whatever I return from -knobThickness method. I actually solved adding a width property to NSSliderCell and overriding - (NSRect)knobRectFlipped:(BOOL)flipped

Comment: Yeah, that seems more correct. Whoops!

Comment: @Alessandro please post your answer how you override -(NSRect)knobRectFlipped:(BOOL)flipped method

Answer (score 3):

I actually managed to customise NSSlider knob appearance adding a `width` property to NSSliderCell and overriding 
`- (NSRect)knobRectFlipped:(BOOL)flipped` this way:

```
- (NSRect)knobRectFlipped:(BOOL)flipped {
CGFloat knobCenterPosition = roundf(size.width * self.floatValue / self.maxValue);
// knob should always be entirely visible
knobCenterPosition = MIN(MAX(knobCenterPosition, roundf(KNOB_WIDTH / 2) + KNOB_INSET), size.width - (roundf(KNOB_WIDTH / 2) + KNOB_INSET));
return  NSMakeRect(knobCenterPosition - roundf(KNOB_WIDTH / 2), 0, KNOB_WIDTH, self.cellSize.height);
```

}

I need to change `knobCenterPosition` when the knob would overlap the right or left border of the slider (`KNOB_WIDTH` and `KNOB_INSET` are self explaining macros).

Comment: @rene after reading [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) I decided to post an answer. Was I wrong?

Comment: I couldn't clearly make out if this was an actual answer or a new update to your question. If this is an answer that is perfectly fine.